# Double negation in French?

Tags: négation, questions

How would you respond negatively to the following question:

> Q. Chacun a fait un exercice?

Is it:

> A. Aucun a fait un exercice.

Or

> A. Aucun n'a pas fait un exercice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say:

> Personne n'a fait d'exercice. (Nobody has done any exercise.)

Comment: @cl-r: Je pense qu'utiliser «ne» sans «pas» est correct. Pour signifier «tout le monde l'a fait» il faudrait écrire «Personne ne l'a pas fait»

Comment: This sentence doesn't sound right to me. I could say “*Personne n'a fait d'exercice*”, or “*Personne n'a fait un seul exercice*” (which to a mathematician means that each person did either zero or at least two exercices, but to anybody else means that each person did zero exercices).

Comment: See the revision history to understand the above comment
https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/7320/revisions

Answer (score 3):

To give you the long answer:

In fact, you were not trying to make a double negation, but to build a negative in French.

You thought that "aucun" was a negative pronoun, meaning "no-one". You were not far, but you fell into a treacherous trap: it is a positive. "Aucun" really means "a few" (or rather meant, because it is quite obsolete) and it is a plural:

> D'aucuns sont venus.

The only negation in French is **ne** (n').

> Aucun... ne => No a few => No one

Since in French (as a thumb rule) zero is a singular, you now have to say:

> **Aucun n'est venu.**

But "aucun", used in that negative way, should refer to people/things you already referred to (why that is, is probably a question of habit). So if it is clear which group of students you are talking about, it is perfectly correct.

To avoid that problem, you should use "**personne**". Personne is also a positive. It really means... "someone".

> "As-tu vu personne?" = "As-tu vu quelqu'un"? => "Have you seen **someone**?"

**In French, the only negation is "ne" (n').**

> ne... personne / personne... ne => "not one" => **nobody**

Hence

> **Personne n'a fait...**

The problem is, modern French usage tends to forget this and the meaning of "personne" is **reversed**, to mean "no-one":

> - As tu vu quelqu'un?
>
> - Non, personne

The only way to tell is with the context. I tend to avoid this, if I can, because it is ambiguous.

**"Un/de" in negative sentences**

And finally, a little detail (not mandatory, but it will improve the quality of your French): in a negative sentence, "un" tends to become "de".

> - As-tu vu un chien?
>
> - Non je n'ai pas vu **de** chien.

Hence the final answer could be:

> **Personne n'a fait d'exercice.**

Answer (score 0):

The logical, negative answer to the question:

> ***Chacun*** a fait un exercice ?

can be:

> *Non, **chacun** n'a pas fait un exercice.*

or the equivalent:

> *Non, **tous** n'ont pas fait un exercice.*

meaning at least one person didn't do one exercise<sup>1</sup>.

> *Non, **il y en a au moins un** qui n'a pas fait d'exercice.*

The reply suggested elsewhere so far:

> ***Personne*** n'a fait d'exercice.

is negatively answering to a different question which is:

> **Quelqu'un** a fait un exercice ?

<sup>1 - or everyone did more than one exercise but this would be controversial.</sup>